# Почему не добавляется перенос строки при записи в файл?

Tags: java

Необходимо записать строки из массива в текстовый файл, каждую с новой строки. Я уже везде добавил переносы строк \n - но почему то все записывается одной строкой.

```
String[] list = {
                "Строка 1 \n",
                "Строка 2\n",
                "Строка 3\n"};

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter("C:\\javaproject\\someFIle.txt"));
        for (String s : list) {
            writer.write(s + "\n");
        }
        writer.close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В блокноте для переноса строки используется `\r\n`

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю, что если хотите поставить перенос строк не зависимо от платформы, то можно воспользоваться несколькими способами

1. Использовать форматирование и один из его кодовых символов. В частности `%n`, Например

   ```
   Calendar c = ...;
   String s = String.format("Duke's Birthday: %1$tm %1$te,%1$tY%n", c); 
                                                                ^---
   ```

   `n` - line separator (разделитель линий), который "рисует" его по разному, в зависимости от платформы, на которой запущен скрипт

   Для бОльших деталей смотри [в документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)
2. Использовать `System.getProperty("line.separator")` ([доки](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties())). Который точно также ставит разделитель в зависимости от платформы.

   Чтобы не писать такую гигантскую конструкцию каждый раз, можно его куда-нибудь вынести

   ```
   final String sp = System.getProperty("line.separator");
   ```

   и потом использовать

   ```
   writer.write(text + sp);
   ```
3. Хотя в *Java7* можно писать уже и так:

   ```
   System.lineSeparator();
   ```

   [доки](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--)

---

Еще вариант самого `BufferedWriter`, использовать `newLine();`

```
writer.write(s);
writer.newLine();
```